# How can I read a variable from c sharp into python?

Tags: c#, python

I want to read variable from c sharp into python.

**.cs file**

```
class MyClass
{    
    string str = "Hello world";
}
```

**.py file**

```
fp = open(path, 'r').read()
#str = ???
print 'str: ' + str
```

When I run my python code, I want to get result:

```
str: Hello world
```

Comment: Use readlines. + regex to find the string you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex, and I strongly suggest using `with` to open your file since you could save some lines of code when closing your file.

```
import re
path = 'my_file.cs'
var_name = 'str'
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(r'{} = "(.*?)"'.format(var_name), line)
        if match:
            print('{}: {}'.format(var_name, match.group(1)))
```

**Output:**

```
str: Hello world
```

In this case, I am assuming your file is in the same directory as your python file, but you can change the path variable if not.

Comment: Thx. But I want to use another directory

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally you'd want to use a parser that's smart enough to know C#. But you can kind of cheat with regex and make it work for this example.

```
import re

fp = open(path, 'r').read()
match = re.search(r'str = "(.*?)"', fp)

print("Str: %s" % match.group(1))
```

Comment: this code return error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'